# Application crash on android

Tags: java, android, button, crash, onclick

I don't know the reason of the crash.

```
package com.tct.soundTouch;

//imports ();;;;;;;

    public class Main extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

        private MediaPlayer mp;
        private MotionEvent event;

        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            final ImageButton zero = (ImageButton) this.findViewById(R.id.button);
            zero.setOnClickListener(this);

            mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound);

        }


        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                mp.setLooping(true);
                mp.start();
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                mp.pause();
                break;

            }
        }

    }
```

the log
[image]

thanks

Comment: line 34: switch (event.getAction()) {

Comment: Now I'm 100% sure that my answer is correct :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not seeing `event` being set to a non-null value in the code you posted. Unfortunately, there is no "up" or "down" to a click event received via an `OnClickListener`.

If you're looking for a toggle-like effect, you might use `MediaPlayer#isPlaying()`:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (mp.isPlaying()) {
        mp.pause();
    } else {
        mp.setLooping(true);
        mp.start();
    }
}
```

If you need to handle `MotionEvent.UP` and `MotionEvent.DOWN` then you should implement [View.OnTouchListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html):

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            mp.setLooping(true);
            mp.start();
            return true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            mp.pause();
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

and then set it using `setOnTouchListener`:

`zero.setOnTouchListener(this);`

Comment: thanks for your answer. But i need the use the events ACTION_UP and ACTION_DOWN. When button is pressed, sound is played, when btn is not pressed music stops

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is in the line  `switch (event.getAction()) {`. Where did you initialize event? I think this causes the NullPointerException.

Btw... You shouldn't name your class main. Use Main at least.

Comment: i have this in the code: private MotionEvent event; so it is defined.
Thanks

Comment: so, what is your advice? how i can initialize the event?

Comment: You can just initialize an event in this case. But depending on what you're trying to do I would recommend Matthew Willis solution.

Comment: @Fel But the main problem is that the button does not have events like ACTION_UP or ACTION_DOWN. The button is just clicked.

Comment: yes, the problem is that. I need the events ACTION_UP or ACTION_DOWN.

Comment: i just change to onTouth and the problem is solved. Thanks Roflcoptr